# Find the probability that you will talk with the number you dial for free.

Tags: probability, statistics

A faulty public phone is such that it returns the coin with probability $60\%$, gives you the number you dial with probability $20\%$, and it takes your coin but does not give you the required connection with probability $30\%$. Find the probability that you will talk with the number you dial for free. I get the answer $10\%$. It it correct?

Comment: so it's $0.60 \cdot 0.20$ or is it required to get the connection? in that case it would be $0.60 \cdot 0.20 \cdot (1-0.30)$

Comment: How did you get the answer $10\%$?

Comment: I think you should use Bayes formula to get correlation beteween the two events "you get the coin back" and "gives the number you dial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\{\text{wrong number }\cup \text{ not free}\}$$
$$=P\{\text{wrong number}\}+P\{\text{not free}\}-P\{\text{wrong number }\cap \text{ not free}\}=0.9$$

and

$$P\{\text{correct number }\cap \text{ free}\}=0.1$$

Comment: That's the way I did it too, getting the same answer.